# How do I include a SQLite DLL in my C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite, dll

I'm trying to add SQLite to my project via a DLL.

I downloaded SQLiteDLL-3 from the [download page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), extracted its contents (a DLL and a .h file), and ran lib.exe on it to produce a .lib file. I then set the directory containing the .lib and the .dll files to be an Additional Library Directory, in the project settings, under Linker >> General.

Then I downloaded SQLiteSource-3 from the download page, and extracted the SQLite3.h file to the directory with the .Lib and .DLL files, and added that directory as an Additional Include Directory under C/C++ >> General. I added #include to my main file, and then added sqlite3.dll as an Additional Dependency in Linker >> Input.

Basically I followed [this](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=332251), but when I run it, I get an error saying:

```
fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2B8
```

I tried a number of things to correct it, including building the .lib file under both x86 and x64, and including the full path to the .lib file in the Additional Dependencies list. It's always that error that I get. It seems to at least be finding the .h file okay, because if I mess with the name in the include, I get a "cannot find the file" error, so that part appears to be correct.

Can someone see what I might be doing incorrectly and how to correct the issue?

**Update:**
Fixed the "invalid or corrupt file" issue by adding the .lib file to the Additional Dependies list, as opposed to the .dll file. Now I'm getting unresolved linker errors:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_exec referenced in function _main

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_open referenced in function _main

fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Comment: you add the .lib file as a linker input, not the .dll file.

Comment: That cleared up that error. Thank you. Now I'm getting unresolved external symbol linker errors for each call to a SQLite function. The functions show up in intellisense, if that matters at alll.

Comment: What's one of the missing symbols?  (Should say in the error)

Comment: _sqlite3_exec and _sqlite3_open.

Comment: The most common suggestion I've found via Google is to "add the library to the project". I've got the library's directory added under Linker >> General >> Additional Library Directories, and the library itself (sqlite3.lib) listed under Linker >> Input >> Additional Dependencies. Does that mean that I've "added it to the project"? I've tried both just adding the file name (assuming that the Additional Library Directories would help it find the file), and the full absolute path, but both still yield the unresolved linker errors.

Comment: how you have created .lib file?

Comment: Also be sure to add it to your "Additional Dependencies" for BOTH Debug and Release modes!

Answer (score 17):

Here's what worked for me:

In Visual Studio 2010, click on "Tools, VS Command Prompt"

In the command line window, enter, for example:

```
lib /DEF:"C:\SQLite\sqlite3.def" /OUT:"C:\SQLite\sqlite3.lib"
```

In the Solution Explorer window, right-click on your project, add the "sqlite3.lib" file.

(You'd think the SQLite gang could include a .lib in the download?)

Comment: How do we do it in Visual Studio 2012? It gives me the error `Command "lib" is not valid.`

Comment: This fixes the "unresolved external" message for me, and the app runs ... and immediately crashes.  `Unable to activate Windows Store app ....  The process ... started, but the activation request failed with error "The app didn't start".`

Comment: My mistake -- the answer here works for me also (my above comment is due to me building x86 for an x64 project, like a dumbass).

Comment: For people who are experiencing the issue of `Command "lib" is not valid.`, you'll just need to go to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin` directory, then use command prompt to run lib.exe.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right sqlite is written in C.
Does the sqlite3.h file have

```
extern "C" {}
```

wrapping the declarations? You might be having [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) issues.

Comment: It does indeed. Any suggestions as to a solution?

Comment: When you run the program the dll file has to be in the same directory as the executable, or in the windows directory. (The lib file does not)

Comment: On your compile issues: I think you're using netbeans as an IDE? You've put in the directory where the lib file can be found but haven't told the project to include that specific library. Under Linker >> General >> Libraries >> Add Library File  then choose the sqlite3.lib file.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio. I ended up just shelling out to another app to do the inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Update: SQLite 3.28 doesn't seem to ship with a .DEF file. To create the DEF and LIB, do:

```
:: Dump SQLite.DLL exports

set DUMPBIN="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86\dumpbin.exe"
set LIBX="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86\lib.exe"
set SQL="C:\SQLite\sqlite3.dll"
set DEF="C:\SQLite\sqlite3.def"
set LIB="C:\SQLite\sqlite3.lib"

:: [1] run dumpbin
%DUMPBIN% /EXPORTS /NOLOGO /OUT:%DEF% %SQL%

:: [2] manually edit .DEF file to look proper
:: [3] run LIB
%LIBX% /DEF:%DEF% /OUT:%LIB%
```